# Remove thousands(k) in plotly line plot

Tags: pandas, plotly

I have plotly line plot with x axis year & week as integer. I do get correct data for year weeks 202101,202102,202103. In plot it shows as 202.1K,202.1K, 202.1K. I am looking for to show 202101,202102, 202103 in plot axis as well. Below is my code.

if chart_choice == 'line':
print(dff['week'])

```
        dff = dff.groupby(['product','week'], as_index=False)[['CYSales']].sum()
        fig = px.line(dff, x='week', y=num_value, color='product')
             
        return fig
```

thanks for help

Comment: Does this help? https://community.plotly.com/t/replacing-thousand-separator-k-with-comma/20666

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `tickformat = "000"` help perhaps? Have a look here [Plotly for R: Remove the k that apears on the y axis when the dataset contains numbers larger than 1000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39735303/plotly-for-r-remove-the-k-that-apears-on-the-y-axis-when-the-dataset-contains-n)

Comment: Great this is exactly what I needed. thank you

Comment: follow-up question, I have year ending week 202052 and next one is 202101 in data set . For some reason its doing cum. I am getting 202053, 202054, 202055..202099 and then 202101. Is there any work around for this? thanks

Comment: This answer did not work for me when using Choropleth Maps. I can't get rid of the undesirable *k*s in my plot.